# Migrating Typekit account for website - Need to change font-family entries?

Tags: css, font-family, typekit

**My question: Is there a way I can configure my Typekit account so that the font names match with the initial account?**

**The explanation:**

I am in the process of migrating a site from one typekit account to another.

The issue I am having is that the first account has all its font names ending with -1, so that the css of the website currently has font-family entries like this:

```
font-family: 'museo-sans-1';
font-family: 'superclarendon-1';
```

Since I do not own this typekit account (hence the reason for the switch), I can't go in an see why the font names are defined as such.

On my typekit account, if I want to use the same fonts, I would need to change the font-family entries to this:

```
font-family: 'museo-sans';
font-family: 'superclarendon';
```

Does anyone know why it's behaving this way (the -1)?

I tried checking the box that says “Include variation-specific font-family names” but it doesn’t seem to work, as the font names all end with –LETTER 1 (for example: museo-sans-n1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got an answer back from Typekit's support personel. I think sharing it here will help the internet (hopefully)!

This is a copy/paste from the e-mail I got from them:

> The font family names that end in -1/-2 is an old convention that
>   Typekit no longer uses. It is still in place on kits that were created
>   during that time, because we didn't want to force users to edit their
>   CSS.
>
> Since you have created a new kit, you will have to update the site CSS
>   to use the newer font family name, e.g. "museo-sans".